# Convert free function to DefaultConstructible function object

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a type which would convert a free function to a default constructible function object.

It should be a class template which would take the function as a template parameter:

```
template<typename F, F P>
struct fn_to_type {
    template<class... Args>
    decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args) {
        return P(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }  
};
```

So it can be used as a template parameter for containers and smart pointers:

```
bool CloseHandle(void* handle);
using UniqueHandle = std::unique_ptr<void, fn_to_type<decltype(&CloseHandle), &CloseHandle>>;

bool FooLess(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs);
using FooSet = std::set<Foo, fn_to_type<decltype(&FooLess), &FooLess>>;
```

The Standard library definitely doesn't have such function, but maybe the Boost libraries do?

Also I'm curious why such thing is not in the standard library - are there any pitfalls which I can't see?

And if there is no library with such function, is there a way to improve this `fn_to_type` thing? E.g. do something to avoid typing function name twice?

Comment: Does your `fn_to_type` not work?

Comment: anyways, I'm asking if there is an existing library with such template.

Comment: what is wrong with your `fn_to_type`?

Comment: @tobi303 that's what I'm asking. did you read the last two lines?

Comment: @Abyx: On Stack Overflow we ask actual questions, not just dump a piece of code and say "isn't it obvious"?

Comment: Why do you ask for something that you already have? I mean what you want to do sounds quite exotic to me, on the other hand it looks like you could get it in some lines by using only stanard c++ stuff. I would not expect to find something like this in the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Standard Library already has a class which can convert a function pointer to a default-constructible class type:

```
template <class T, T v>
struct integral_constant {
    ...
    constexpr operator value_type() { return value; }
};
```

Thus it can be used instead of that `fn_to_type` class:

```
#include <type_traits>

bool CloseHandle(void* handle);
using UniqueHandle = std::unique_ptr<void, std::integral_constant<decltype(&CloseHandle), &CloseHandle>>;

bool FooLess(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs);
using FooSet = std::set<Foo, std::integral_constant<decltype(&FooLess), &FooLess>>;
```

Comment: Thanks to **David Krauss** for [pointing to this solution](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-proposals/ANAWFoMvr5Y/pYL0ty_r6H8J)

Comment: `integral_constant` is not callable.

Comment: @Lingxi it has `operator value_type()`