# How to wrap C allocation returning error code using RAII

Tags: c++, c, raii

I realize that similar questions have been asked [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14808783/wrap-c-allocation-for-raii), but I couldn't find an answer that's a good fit for my function signatures.

Consider this typical pair of C functions:

```
int initFoo(Options options, Foo* foo);
void freeFoo(Foo* foo);
```

`initFoo` takes some options and a pointer to an uninitialized `Foo` struct. It initializes this struct and returns a result code that indicates whether the initialization was successful. `freeFoo` frees an initialized `Foo` struct.

Now assume I want to use these C functions in my C++ code. I want to use RAII, so I need to construct a `unique_ptr<Foo>` that will automatically call `freeFoo` on destruction. The best approach I could come up with is this:

```
template<typename T>
using lambda_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, std::function<void(T*)>>;

lambda_unique_ptr<Foo> createFoo(Options options) {
    Foo* foo = new Foo();
    const int resultCode = initFoo(options, foo);
    if (resultCode != 0) throw ...;

    return lambda_unique_ptr<Foo>(foo, [](Foo* foo) {
        freeFoo(foo);
        delete foo;
    });
}
```

I'm certain that there must be a more elegant solution. Ideally, something more functional that doesn't require so many individual steps. What I find particularly ugly is the necessity to explicitly allocate the `Foo` struct on the heap, then explicitly free and delete it in two steps. Any ideas?

Comment: Does `allocFoo` not really _allocate_ Foo?  It expects a pointer to an already-allocated Foo?  Does `freeFoo` not free the memory?

Comment: @DrewDormann: I made up those names to make the question more generic. In light of your comment, I renamed `allocFoo` to `initFoo`. And yes, `initFoo` expects a pointer to an existing struct.

Comment: @DanielWolf So `initFoo` and `freeFoo` don't actually handle memory? They're like constructors and destructors for Foo?

Comment: Typically I would expect those calls to be symmetrical. That is `initFoo` - `unintFoo` (no dynamic memory management) or `allocFoo` - `freeFoo` (both initialization / unitialization and dynamic memory management)

Comment: Does `freeFoo` not free the memory?  If it doesn't, I'd imagine the C code having as many steps as your C++ wrapper.

Comment: I'm sorry if the names I chose cause confusion. For a real example, consider [`ov_fopen`](https://xiph.org/vorbis/doc/vorbisfile/ov_fopen.html) and [`ov_clear`](https://xiph.org/vorbis/doc/vorbisfile/ov_clear.html) from the Vorbis library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just wrap `Foo` in a class?

```
struct FooWrap {
    Foo foo;

    explicit FooWrap(Options options) {
        if (initFoo(options, &this->foo))
            throw ...;
    }

    ~FooWrap() {
        freeFoo(&this->foo);
    }

    // XXX: either implement or disable assignment and copy construction
};
```

Now you can choose whether to just define `FooWrap x(42);` as an automatic variable or whether to allocate it dynamically with `new`.

Comment: I was going for a `unique_ptr` because of its established interface. But maybe you're right and this case calls for its own class.

Comment: This is better than using a `unique_ptr` in two ways that I notice - it's faster to access than a pointer reference to the heap, and it can be copied as long as `Foo` can be copied.